# How to create a calendar from an array of events?

Tags: php, wordpress, calendar

I'm working in Wordpress, and I'm getting a custom post type called events.

In my array where I have retrieved the events using `get_posts()`, I have all of the events in order by date from oldest to newest.

No what I'm trying to achieve is basically a monthly calendar of these events.

I know how to loop over these and group them into years and days. But I don't know how to add empty days in between.

Here's a snippet of code for example:

```
$events = array(
    array('Event 1', '2015-04-03'),
    array('Event 2', '2015-04-03'),
    array('Event 3', '2015-06-16'),
    array('Event 4', '2015-06-29'),
    array('Event 5', '2015-07-04'),
    array('Event 6', '2015-12-25'),
    array('Event 7', '2016-01-01')
)
```

What I can currently do:

```
2015
  April
    3
      Event 1
      Event 2
  June
    16
      Event 3
    29
      Event 4

    ...
```

What I'm looking to do is start with the first month from the first day of that month, and go through all days and end on the last day of that month. Basically I'm trying to create a calendar.

So what I'm trying to get is:

```
2015
  April
    1
      empty
    2 
      empty
    3
      Event 1
      Event 2
    4
      empty
    5
      empty

    ...
```

Etc... that way I can loop through all days to create a calendar. But I also don't want to include months that don't have events. So I can't just pick the first event's date and the last event's date in my array and create the calendar from that, there could be months that have no events, which I wouldn't want to show.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
for ($date = strtotime("2015-04-01"); $date < strtotime("2016-01-01"); $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date)) {
    echo date("Y-m-d", $date)."";
}
```

This of course doesn't get my events, nor does it skip the empty months, but it's what I'm starting from.

What is the best way to do this without running a ton of queries?

Comment: Run one query to get all events and sort them by date? After that you can check whether each day of the year matches the date of the next event (and if it does check the one after etc, to cover multiple events on one day).

Comment: As explained above, I can already do this.

Comment: So you have all the data in an array, so only one query. I'd then loop by month and within each month loop by day - if a day has no events echo empty, and if all the days within a month have no events don't echo the month.

Comment: The issue is my loop starts with the first event, not the first day of that month. I want to include all days of a month to create a calendar.

Comment: Ah - I see the issue. You need to check the entire month first and save the result to a variable e.g. `$output` then only echo that if at least one event was found.

Comment: @JohnCH right, that's what I technically don't know how to do.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies things perfectly, I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Having woken up this morning I realised that there's a much easier and better way than recursive functions!**

Here it is:

```php
$start_date = strtotime("2015-01-01");
$end_date = strtotime("2016-01-01");

$event_no = 0;

for ($date = $start_date; $date  < $end_date; $date = strtotime("+1 month", $date)) {
    $out = "The Month";
    $contains_events = false;
    for ($day = $date; $day  < strtotime("+1 month", $date); $day = strtotime("+1 day", $day)) { 
        foreach ($events as $k => $event) {
            if ($k < $event_no) continue; // Starts the loop where we left off
            if (date("Y-m-d", $day) == $event[1]) {
                $contains_events = true;
                $out .= $event[0]; // Obviously these outputs will require a little formatting.
                $event_no++;
            } else {
                $out .= "Empty";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if($contains_events) echo $out;
}
```

**My old answer**

The simplest way I could see to do this was to implement a self-calling function to check a specific date as this allows multiple events on a date to be added easily.

You can do the looping through like this:

```php
$start_date = strtotime("2015-01-01");
$end_date = strtotime("2016-01-01");

$event_no = 0;

for ($date = $start_date; $date  < $end_date; $date = strtotime("+1 month", $date)) {

    // For each month

    $out = "The Month";
    $contains_events = false;

    for ($day = $date; $day  < strtotime("+1 month", $date); $day = strtotime("+1 day", $day)) { 

        // For each day in month

        $day_check = check_day($events, $event_no, $day); // Check if day has events

        if($day_check) {
            $out .= $day_check;
            $contains_events = true;
        } else $out .= "Empty";
    }
    if($contains_events) echo $out;
}
```

Then, assuming data as in your example, you can check each day for events with this function:

```php
function check_day($events, &$event_no, $day) {
    if (date("Y-m-d", $day) == $events[$event_no][1]) {

        $ret = $events[$event_no][0]; // Obviously these outputs will require a little formatting.
        $event_no++;
        $ret .= check_day($events, $event_no, $day);
        return $ret;
    } else return null;
}
```

I've done my best with these, but I haven't had time to actually test them so I apologise if there are some issues.

Comment: For some reason there is loop recursion and I've narrowed it down to the inner day loop. Any thoughts?

Comment: That inner loop is designed to be recursive! Can you post the actual error message you're getting?

Comment: Found the issue there - the for loop is adding one to the month date each time, change $date to $day! Edited answer